# Is it true that the Fermi-Dirac distribution is a probability?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is it true that the Fermi-Dirac distribution is a *probability* ?

I checked by doing the integral, and this does not give 1.

[image]

Also, for $T=0 K$, since it is a step function, it is easy to see that the integral will be $E_F$, different to 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the normalization constant of Fermi-Dirac distribution function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220881/how-to-find-the-normalization-constant-of-fermi-dirac-distribution-function)

Comment: @Aaron Stevens : no, because Fermi Dirac function does not have A in the numerator. The only thing that could appear is the degeneracy factor, but not $[2 / (2\pi \hbar^3)]$, and even with this factor, the integral would not give 1.

Comment: Did you read the posted answer there?

Comment: yes, fore sure, and the answer of this states the Fermi-Dirac is the one that I have put. The point is that I believe that it is not a probability function. And this discussion goes in my direction that I'm right : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446773/are-the-fermi-dirac-bose-einstein-and-boltzmann-distributions-all-probabilities

Comment: f is between 0 and 1, fore sure, but it is not a *probability function*, since integral of f is different to 1. Just look at the link that I gave. This is why I wanted to have a definitive conclusion.

Comment: Correct, it is not a probability. And nobody says so. It's the expectation of the number operator in $k$ space.

Comment: All right, thank you very much @lcv

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fermi-Dirac distribution (also the Bose-Einstein) does not give the probability of finding the fermion (boson) in a given energy region. What this distribution provides is the probability of finding a state with energy E being occupied by a fermion (boson), so It doesn't have to give 1 when integrated in the whole system. Note how the FD function is limited to one, remember that two fermions cannot occupy the same quantum state (actually, you should multiply the distribution $f(E_i)$ by $g_i$, being $g_i$ the degeneracy of the state with energy $E_i$, i.e this would take into consideration the spin), in the case of BE statistics this does not happen, since bosons can actually share a quantum state!

Another point I wanted to make, you should use the chemical potential, $\mu$, instead of $E_F$. The Fermi energy is fixed for the system and it's defined as $E_F=\mu(T=0)$.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What @Manuel Gallego is saying that for each state of energy $E$ we have
$$
P({\rm empty})= \frac{1}{(1+e^{-\beta (E-\mu)})}, \quad P({\rm occupied})= \frac{e^{-\beta (E-\mu)}}{(1+e^{-\beta (E=\mu)})},
$$
so $P({\rm empty})+P({\rm occupied})=1$, and for $n=0$ or $n=1$ we have
$$
\langle n\rangle = \frac{0\times 1}{(1+e^{-\beta (E-\mu)})}+ \frac{1 \times e^{-\beta (E-\mu)}}{(1+e^{-\beta (E-\mu)})}
\\
= \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta (E-\mu)}}
$$
which is the F-D distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The Fermi occupation function

$$ n(\epsilon)= \frac{1}{e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}+1},$$

is not a probability density function. The normalisation condition is that:

$$N = \sum_i \bar{n}_i, $$

where $\bar{n}_i=n(\epsilon_i)$ is the mean occupation number of a 1-particle state with energy $\epsilon_i$, and where the sum is over all one particle states. Thus the numbers

$$ p_i = \frac{\bar{n}_i}{N},$$

are indeed probabilities, which is why the Fermi occupation factor might sometimes be referred to as giving the occupation probabilities. Note however that it is strictly speaking a probability *mass* function not a *density* function. To get a *density* you have to multiply by the *density* of states. That is, it is not correct to write:

$$\sum_i \bar{n}_i \underbrace{\approx}_{\rm \color{red}{wrong}} \int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}\epsilon}{e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}+1}. $$

Instead, what is correct is that but with an additional factor, known as the density of states $g(\epsilon)$ included in the integral on the right hand side. In the case of a 3-D non-relativistic ideal gas for instance there are more states at per energy interval at larger energies, scaling like $g(\epsilon)\sim \sqrt{\epsilon}$.